# Google Sheet Code for checking Duplicate domain in a google sheet column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have some data in a column name URLs in google sheets.
Suppose [data in google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjlOj.jpg)

As you can see, there are unique domain names and some of them are duplicates as well but they have different slug/permalink.

Is there any conditional formatting code that can color code the duplicate of all websites(not a single) with red color?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(    
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A$1:A, "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)")),     
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)"))))>1
```

[image]